# Переопределение функции базового класса kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Когда я хочу переопределить метод из базового класса, добавив туда новые параметры, то у меня `override` подсвечивается красным цветом и пишет нечего переопределять. Вопрос: мы можем получается изменять только сам функционал класса?

Код:

```kotlin
open class Person() {
    open fun info(name:String){
        println("Hi $name")
    }
}

class Man:Person(){
    override fun info(name:String,age:Int){
        super.info("Yar`введите сюда код`")
        println("hi $name $age")
    }
}
```

Comment: А какая цель "переопределения метода из базового класса, добавив туда новые параметры"?

Comment: например для того, чтобы вывести имя, которое является параметром

Comment: Что мешает определить дополнительный метод без использования override?

Comment: В том то и дело, что ничего. Я просто пытался полностью понять все ньюансы переопределения

Answer (score 1):

Можно переопределить только методы с такими же параметрами (тип и количество), как в родительском. Поэтому нужно добавить в родительский класс метод с такой же сигнатурой:

```
open fun info(name: String, age: Int) {
    // do your stuff
}
```